# How do I calculate the Sound Striker bard's Weird Words attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, class-feature, bard, touch-attacks

Bard [Sound Striker](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/archetypes/paizo-bard-archetypes/sound-striker/) Archetype has 2 new bardic performances, one which is Weird Words and reads as:

> Weird Words (Su): At 6th level the bard can start a performance that is always a standard action to speak up to one word per 4 bard levels laden with sonic energy. Each word deals 4d6 points of sonic damage as a ranged touch attack with a range of 30 feet. The bard adds his charisma modifier on damage rolls with weird words. Multiple words that strike the same target stack into a single powerful attack, applying energy resistance and bonuses on damage rolls only once. The bard can target all words at the same or different targets, but he unleashes all words simultaneously. Each word costs 1 round of bardic performance.

Normally for a Bardic Performance I roll my performance skill, my question here is do I get to use the performance skill for the attack roll or I just roll a d20 for the ranged touch attack?

Also do ranged feats like point blank shot and precise shot affect this performance?

Comment: ...and what stat would you use to make this attack?

Comment: @BenBarden - Looking.

Answer (score 5):

### Threat as a regular ranged magical touch attack

This is a [ranged attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/combat/#TOC-Attack-Bonus), but there is very little information about this working as other types of attacks, such as rays or weapon attacks.

- You attack using 1d20 + your *Base Attack Bonus* + your Dexterity *modifier*.

And for damage, the ability says you deal 4d6 plus your Charisma modifier as bonus damage. But since you apply resistances and bonus to these damage rolls only once, shouting multiple words should apply your Charisma modifier only once.

- Your damage is 4d6 (per word) + your Charisma *modifier*.

It is also considered a magical attack because it is a [Supernatural](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/special-abilities/#TOC-Supernatural-Abilities-Su-) ability. And because it is a [Ranged Touch Attack](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering/Combat/#TOC-Touch-Attacks), it is rolled against the target(s) touch AC.

Finally, you said that you normally use your Perform skill for [bardic performances](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/bard/), but that is only valid for specific performances, like *Countersong* or *Distraction*. Using *Inspire Courage* or *Inspire Competence* (or even this *Wordstrike* ability) does not require any *Perform* checks from your character.

> do ranged feats like point blank shot and precise shot affect this performance?

Yes, see [this FAQ](https://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fm#v5748eaic9uxg). [Point-Blank](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/point-blank-shot-combat/), [Precise Shot](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/precise-shot-combat/) and everything that is normally used with ranged attacks may be used with *Weird Words*, which also means you may provoke *Attacks of Opportunity* when using the ability while threatened and must take a -4 penalty to your checks when attacking an enemy that is within reach of an ally.

Again, keep in mind that bonuses to damage are only applied once, so *Point-Blank* can only grant its damage bonus once, even if you shout multiple words against the same target.

Comment: I'm not saying that you're wrong, but it seems a bit odd that it would be dex-based rather than cha-based.

Comment: @BenBarden It would take specific language to change it, and, since that's not present, I agree that this seems right on. Yeah, the sound striker is literally shooting words at folks, like an even weirder version of the 1960s *Batman* television series.

Comment: Huh.  A musician attacking enemies with weaponized rays of magical sound?  I've *seen* that 80s movie and/or cartoon

Comment: Correct, except I think that the Charisma modifier is added to each word but only once per enemy "Multiple words that strike the same target stack into a single powerful attack, applying energy resistance **and bonuses on damage rolls only once.**"

Comment: Also, the question was altered to include verifying if ranged feats apply.

Comment: That was my initial understanding as well. No clue why I changed it.

Comment: "Also" is a good indicator of a second question.